# How to ADD a delay to coaxial tv signal?

Tags: delay

Is there a way to add a delay that can be increased/deceased as required to a coaxial tv signal?

Comment: 5000 miles of coaxial cable?

Comment: Your question is meaningless.  There is no such thing as a "coaxial TV signal".  There are TV services transmitted over coaxial cable, but they are encoded and modulated and not just a "TV signal".

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called TiVo ;)

Comment: How much delay do you need?

Comment: Ok, ignoring the word tv, is it possible to delay a signal over coaxial? TiVo is a bit expensive for what I'm trying to achieve :-(

Comment: Between 1 and 10 seconds delay

Comment: TiVo costs less than 5,000 miles of cable, and a broad spectrum delay loop synthesizer would cost even more.

Comment: Moonbounce ought to do it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-Moon-Earth_communication

Comment: I'd like to know why you want to delay the signal between 1 and 10 seconds. Call it curiosity.

Comment: I will try to dampen your curiosity then Andy. I use a proxy to get bbc and itv via xbmc so I can watch the world cup with english commentary (i live in Sweden). Quality is so so on the video but I can have the Swedish digital tv via antenna which is perfect quality and the audio via xbmc. Problem is it is out of sync with the digital via antenna always ahead by a second to a few seconds.

Answer (score 5):

OK, let's assume you're talking about an analog signal that has a bandwidth of about 5 MHz, and you need to maintain a signal-to-noise ratio of about 72 dB, or about 12 bits of resolution.

One direct way to delay the signal is to digitize it, write it to a memory and then read it out again at a later time.

To capture a baseband signal with a bandwidth of 5 MHz, you'll need to sample at a minimum of 10 M samples/s. To delay this by up to 10 seconds, you'll need 100 M samples of storage. Call it 200 MB for convenience. SDRAM would be an excellent fit.

You need an ADC, the SDRAM, and a DAC, plus some sort of control interface. You can get fast MCUs, DSPs and FPGAs that all have the necessary SDRAM and I/O interfaces. The choice of what kind of chip works best for you depends on whatever else (if anything) you might want it to be doing.

Comment: Don't forget the demodulation and remodulation hardware - a cable TV signal uses multiple carrier frequencies ranging from 7Mhz right up to 1GHz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_television_frequencies#Channel_frequencies_2

Comment: This answer should work for a single baseband video signal, but certainly won't do for the full "cablevision"/community antenna spectrum.

Comment: I *said* I was addressing the case of a single baseband signal. I can't think of any reason that you'd want to delay the entire contents of a CATV signal by that amount. The usual application for delays in this range is as a transmitter delay for live programs, so that the producer has time to blank out objectionable content.

Comment: @DaveTweed: my appologies if my comment appeared to criticize your answer - I was really responding to Majenko's comment, and should have addressed him specficially.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can simply add more coax. Look at the propagation speed of the coax (usually specified) in the range of 0.6 C (C = speed of light).  So 1.8e8 m/s.  So about 5.6 ns/m length of coax.

Comment: That's the way TV studios used to do it, once upon a time... [ edit : in the microsecond range, not seconds!]

Comment: And PAVE-PAWS phase array radar

Comment: -1, sorry but this is not practical answer

Comment: For a one second delay, that's a lot of coax, and a lot of attenuation.

Comment: @Kamil : it's a perfectly sensible answer to the original question. Only the additional constraints in comments rendered it impractical. Downvote is inappropriate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I downvoted because it's hard to change wire lenght as required, not because answer is wrong or not sensible.

Comment: @Kamil if you'd bother to follow the reference - To the phased array Radar you'd realize that is exactly how the beam was swept.  Yes it is hard and probably impractical for the OP but we don't know that for sure.